# get matches words by regex java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need a method for getting whole word if matches a pattern, for exemple:

```
<p>This is some text. <img src="md5_id=12345" </p>
```

I'll need to get `md5_id=12345`, so pattern will be smth like :`...md5_id:xxxxx...` where `x` can be 0-9 or a-z/A-Z

Comment: I need a million dollar, where can I get it?

Comment: No, the pattern will be like this: import `jsoup`, and access the "src" attribute value with something like `doc.select("img[src^=md5_id]");`

Comment: @nafas At least you have a question

Comment: @johny do you have 1million dollar?

Comment: @nafas you're stupid, if you're so smart and you wanted to give me a lesson to search a solution by myself, you could give me a doc link not beeng so shity...

Comment: @johny i guess you don't have a million dollar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution...

```
    private void method(String txt) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(("md5_id=[a-zA-Z_0-9]{5,}"));

    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(txt);
    while (m.find()) {
        Log.d("log", m.group());

    }
}
```

Comment: there, now u found your own million dollar :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("md5_id=(\\w+)");
```

First,you can try it by yourself ,if have any problem,then we can help you.